# Ubuntu server, stuck in emergency mode

Tags: command-line, server

My Linux system is stuck in emergency mode and it's giving me errors that I can't understand... I've been looking for a way to fix it but in my particular case I haven't found a solution, maybe some of you with more knowledge in Linux can help me. I have included an image of the screen. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: In my experience I end up in emergency mode for one of two reasons: 1) problems with an update to fstab, or partition updates not properly reflected in fstab 2) partition corruption problems that need an fsck. DId you make any recent changes to partitioning or fstab?